# How do I repair armor with similar armor in fallout new vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I searched everywhere for methods on repairing armor and people said that you could ask people to repair armor for you but it's too expensive. Then I saw people saying you could "cannibalize" armor, and by that I mean using similar armor to repair the primary armor set. But I don't see the option to do so. I went to my workbench but it didn't say anything about repairing my armor.

Answer (score 5):

Open the weapons or armour page on your pip-boy and find the item you want to repair. Mouse over it and press r (Y on xbox 360). If you have identical or very similar weapons or armour to use in the repairs, you will see a list of items you can use for repairs. Click them to use them.

Increasing your repair skill will make your repairs more efficient.

The Jury Rigging perk, available at level 14 with 90 repair, allows you to repair any item with any item of the same category. For example, you can repair a magnum revolver with any handgun or repair power armour with any heavy armour.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to be able to repair the armor the same way you repair a weapon on your pip-boy, if both armor are similar, you can "cannibalize" them the same way you cannibalize weapons.

else, there is a list of all NPCs that can repair :

1. Dale Barton- Fortification Hill
2. Samuel Kerr- 188 Trading Post
3. Calamity- Jacobstown
4. Old Lady Gibson- Gibson Scrap Yard
5. Mick- Mick & Ralph's
6. Major Knight- Mojave Outpost
7. Paladin Sato- Brotherhood of Steel Safehouse
8. Raul Tejada- Raul's Shack

Comment: Yes, but I repair my weapons using Weapon Repair Kits, since I don't know how to repair armor/weapons with similar armor/weapons. Is there a certain perk I need to do this, or more points in a certain attribute on my S.P.E.C.I.A.L?

Comment: You're not supposed to need repair skills to repair weapons, just select the weapon, press the repair button (it is something like triangle or Y on console), it will open a list of similar items and you just have to decide the one you want to sacrifice to repair the item you selected. Repair level will increase the repair rate and the quantity you can repair